# Trouble with glTranslatef placement

Tags: c, glut

I have a question about glTranslatef.  My teacher told me to place the call in display() which is defined below:

```
void display()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(program);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexArrayBufferID);

glVertexAttribPointer(vPos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0) );

glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPos);

glTranslatef(transX, transY, transZ);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementArrayBufferID);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numElements, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

transX, transY, and transZ are set to 0.0 initially and are changed using a callback glutKeyboardFunc() that reads the key pressed.  I've tested the callback with cout and it displays the feedback but the image won't translate.  Is there a specific placement required for the program to work?  I checked on Google but haven't found what I'm looking for yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the matrix as well, otherwise the translation will be accumulated every frame until your content is outside the display.

Look up `glLoadIdentity`